# Disable DropArea temporarily

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

How can I bring a QtQuick DropArea to not accept drops? In my case I have a drop area that I want to accept one element at a time only.

My current thought is to implement this using a common key for all drag elements and remove that key for the exclusive area while it contains a drag element.

However that seems rather clumsy. It there something I am missing? I do not want to disable the Area either using `enable = false`, since this will disable the element residing in it and does not allow to drag that element any more.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is the draggable element inside the droparea? If it is, move it outside (in the code) so disabling one won't disable the other.

Comment: Some code to play with would be nice. Can you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I think you should use some properties to check if there is or not some element in the DropArea. You have a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068528).