# QML avoid empty spaces when Drag and Drop Between Views

Tags: qt, qml

I am using the [QtQuick's Drag and Drop example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-draganddrop-example.html) (the Tiles part) to drag and drop tiles (representing buttons) from the list onto the grid as a way to dynamically lay out these buttons.

When "removing" (i.e. reparenting) the tile from the list, an empty space is left. I would like the list to automatically reorganize to close this gap. Is that possible using the approach in the example where the drag/drop is simply done by reparenting the tile? Or do I need to have two models (one for the list and one for the grid) and add/remove the dragged item between the two models?

Thanks for your help!

See this image

[image]

to get a better idea of what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because in the example they just apply a parent change on a child of the tile, so the empty root `Item` remains in the columns:

```
// DragTile.qml
Item {
    id: root
    // ...
    MouseArea {
        // ...
        drag.target: tile
        onReleased: parent = tile.Drag.target !== null ? tile.Drag.target : root
        Rectangle {
            id: tile
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you apply the parent change to the root `Item`, the `Column` will automatically be reorganized:

```
onReleased: {
    if (tile.Drag.target) {
        root.parent = tile.Drag.target
        root.anchors.centerIn = root.parent
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks, that was it! Do you also happen to know how I can prevent a drop on an already occupied cell? In the Qt example, tiles can be dropped one on top of each other, which is not what I want. Or should I ask this in another post?

Comment: To be able to put the tile back in the `Column`, I instead keep everything as in the original example, but just collapse `root.height` to `0`, and set it back to the original value when dragged back.

Comment: To disable the `DropArea` when it is occupied you can use a custom property indicating if the `DropArea` contains an item or not, and reject the drop if needed. [You can find an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38069971/4503757).